# Powershell: Copying files from multiple folders created x days while maintaining folder structure

Tags: powershell

I am having issues maintaining the folder structure during a Powershell copy using **FOREACH** loops as some folders under the parent folder need the data created longer than 90 days ago whereas others 180.

```
$Folders_90Days = "C:\Admin\Ripley","C:\Admin\Android","C:\Admin\Bishop"
$Folders_180Days = "C:\Admin\Archer","C:\Admin\Figgis","C:\Admin\Pam"
$Dest = 'D:\Archive_Target'

FOREACH($path in $Folders_90Days){
$files = (Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)})

ForEACH($file in $Files){
Copy-Item $file.FullName -destination $Dest -Recurse
}
#End ForEach Folders_90Days loop
}
```

When the copy runs, the data copied from the source folders is copied directly into the target.
So in essence the data in `Ripley` copies directly to `Archive_Target`.

How can I get it to copy with the source folder becoming the target folder?
Example:
`D:\Archive_Target\Ripley`
 - All the while maintaining the folder structure of `Source Ripley`?

Comment: I would suggest using Robocopy rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: How would you use Robocopy within Powershell to acheive this? As later when everything is copied to the destination I will use PS to zip it all into an archive.

Comment: Start with typing this at a powershell prompt: `robocopy /?`

Answer (score 0):

Ive created a function that does exactly this without xcopy.

I put it in a workflow that allows Parallel processing.

Using Regex I get the folder that is the base for the source. If the path isnt there create it, else the real meat is in the pipe.
Get all items in source, pipe to a if older then AgeInDays then copy the item and its container which allows for the file structure to keep the same.

```
workflow Copy-ItemBasedOnCreation{
    Param(
        [string[]]$Sources,
        [string]$Desination,
        [int]$AgeInDays
    )

    foreach –parallel ($Source in $Sources){
        $FixedDesination = "$($Desination)$($Source -replace '.*\\')"
        if(!(Test-Path -Path $FixedDesination)){
            md $FixedDesination
        }
        Get-ChildItem  $Source -Recurse | ?{(($_.CreationTime).Day -gt $AgeInDays)} | Copy-Item -Destination $FixedDesination -Recurse -Container
    }
}

Copy-ItemBasedOnCreation -Sources @("C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Source\TEST1","C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Source\TEST2") -Desination "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Destination\" -AgeInDays 90
Copy-ItemBasedOnCreation -Sources @("C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Source\TEST4","C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Source\TEST5") -Desination "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Destination\" -AgeInDays 180
```